# Desvincular dos gráficos dinámicos (modificar uno sin que afecte al otro)

Tags: excel

Buenas, tengo un par de problemas que agradecería bastante si alguien con mas experiencia en el asunto me puede ayudar.

**Contexto:** Estoy creando un sistema en Excel que vincula bases de datos y que automáticamente genera representaciones visuales de la información para la lectura mas rápida y cómoda, hasta ahí todo bien.

> Primera Duda: Existe alguna forma de agrupar en fecha por mes si uno
>   tilda la opción de analizar varias tablas?
>
> [image: http://i.imgur.com/eMEnbev.png]
>
> Dicho de otro modo, viendo la imagen, quiero lograr los **datos
>   agrupados por mes (como se ve en B)** pero activado la opción de
>   **agregar estos datos al modelo de datos (como está marcado en A)**, ya que hasta ahora siempre que lo intento la herramienta de agrupar me
>   aparece en gris (no seleccionable) cuando  activo la opción vista en
>   A.   Mi intención es que varios gráficos interactúen con el mismo
>   filtro de segmento de datos, pero para hacerlo  de una forma que me
>   permita crear varios gráficos con campos distintos distintos de una
>   misma tabla dinámica principal, necesito activar la opción de modelos
>   de datos.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> La segunda, mas que una duda, es un problema que me obliga a crear un
>   archivo de respaldo cada vez que hago algún cambio importante en el
>   archivo,  es que a veces cuando estoy modificando una gráfica
>   dinámica, por arte de magia dos gráficas se vuelven una sola (asumen
>   una misma lista de campo) y por lo tanto se desconfigura por completo
>   la configuración milimétricamente preparada de una de las gráficas x.x
>   jeje, es un error "tonto" que se arregla cerrando y volviendo a abrir
>   el documento, pero me obliga a revisar y probar los filtros y
>   configuración de cada una de las gráficas antes de guardar.
>
> No sé si es que por accidente presiono una combinación de teclas que
>   activa esa función (una función muy extraña por cierto jaja) o es un
>   bug del excel.

PD: ¿Vale la pena el Office 2016? tengo el 2013 y lo único que leo que mejoraron, ademas de la interfaz, es que es mas "social" , y no me convence mucho pagar la nueva licencia solo para que me permita compartir en facebook jeje.

Agradeciendo desde ya la ayuda y el tiempo.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola @Gregorio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Tal vez sea necesario que replantees tu problema para que se ajuste a los estándares de calidad del sitio. Inicialmente te propongo que consultes la página [¿¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí??](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Te recomiendo también que separes tu preguntas, para que haya "una pregunta, un post". Tal vez tu _post_ deba ser cerrado, no lo tomes a mal.

Comment: Hola Gregorio.  Coincido con @toledano en darte la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español y que en sería conveniente que edites tu publicación pues incluyes varias preguntas e incluyes un tema principalmente basado en opiniones además de que el título  corresponde parcialmente a lo que se menciona en el cuerpo de la publicación. Te sugiero leer [ask]. En cuanto a la temática, en [meta] se sugirió que se incluya entre los temas a tratar en este sitio se incluyan las hojas de cálculo.